# Firestore Rules - get() behaviour (bug?)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In Firestore rules I created this function:

```
function rulesTest() {
     let doc = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/someCollection/someDocId);
     return doc == null;
}
```

According to the [documentation of the get() method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore#.get) the return type of it is:

> **non-null rules.firestore.Resource** the document, or null if it does not
> exist

Testing this function on an empty database (so no `someCollection` and no `someDocId`) I am expecting doc to be null and therefore `rulesTest()` to return `true`.

Actual return type is `false`.

**The weird part:**

Even if I change the the return statement to `return doc != null` the function would return `false`.

**edit**: This is happening on Emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Firestore bug: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2067

Use this instead:

```
function safeget(path) {
   return exists(path) ? get(path) : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the problem you have, but it seems to work as expected for me here:

[image]

You can see that my `test76141403` function returns `true` here, because the doc at `/not/existing` does not exist. If I change the test to `!=`, the same function returns `false`.

Comment: did you try this in emulator? I forgot to mention that this is happening on the emulator